# Java program problem: Unexpected value num

Tags: java

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char c = 'A' ;
        int num = 10 ;

        switch(c) {
            case 'B' :
                num++ ;
            case 'A' :
                num++ ;
            case 'Y' :
                num++ ;
                break ;
            default :
                num-- ;
        }

        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

I think the program will passed `case 'A'` so the num will be 11.
I ran it in Idea and saw that the program passed `case 'A'` and `case 'Y'`(???). Finally, the num is 12.

I try this:
`System.out.println('A' == 'Y');`
and it return`false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example the program first passes `case 'A'` since the char in `c` is `A`, but then it "falls through" to `case 'Y'` since `case 'A'` does not end with a `break`.

If this behaviour is not desired, add a `break` to `case 'A'`.

Read https://medium.com/swlh/understanding-switch-case-fall-through-in-java-70b448427b0a for more details.

Comment: Ah, I remember, there would be a break after each case, which was a trap deliberately left by the title.Thanks.